# Finding the caret position in character in a div content editable with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I m having some troubles while getting the cursor caret position inside of a div with contenteditable attribute.

Actually, I m using the following function :

```
  onBlurArea (field, ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    const editable = ev.target.childNodes[1].childNodes[2]
    this.positions[field] = {start: this.getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(editable), editable}
  }

  getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin (element) {
    let ie = (typeof this.doc.selection != 'undefined' && this.doc.selection.type != 'Control') && true
    let w3 = (typeof this.win.getSelection != 'undefined') && true
    let caretOffset = 0
    if (w3) {
      let range = this.win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
      console.log(range)
      let preCaretRange = range.cloneRange()
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element)
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
      console.log(preCaretRange)
      caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length
      console.log(caretOffset)
    }
    else if (ie) {
      let textRange = this.doc.selection.createRange()
      let preCaretTextRange = this.doc.body.createTextRange()
      preCaretTextRange.expand(element)
      preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', textRange)
      caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length
    }
    return caretOffset
  }
```

The function onBlurArea is triggered when I blur a text-angular field :

```
<text-angular ng-model="moduleManage.currentModule.description" required ng-blur="moduleManage.onBlurArea('description', $event)"></text-angular>
```

Moreover :

```
this.doc = $document
this.win = $window
```

- I need to get the cursor position to add some external stuff not managed by the library.
- My problem is that when I blur my field, my carretOffset is not the same if I focus on a precise field or on another one.
- The function above always gives me 0
- When I log the range, I m always having a div item that is completely out of my current focus, even out of text-angular module

EDIT : I think my problem is on the following line :

```
let range = this.win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
```

That give me something that I don't understand at all...

Comment: The `startContainer` in `this.win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` is not a child node of your `editable` constant defined in `onBlurArea`?

Comment: Not at all, in fact it's a div that is where I lose my focus. For example, if I click a button outside the div, the button will be my startContainer. It's the same case for any other kind of element...

Comment: Oh that's right that is exactly how `blur` works i think. Faced the same problems before. In this case u cannot get the range after the `blur` event is fired. Maybe u can try store the range every time there is `keyup` or `mouseup` event on the `editable` div. That was how i managed to achieve similar purpose.

Comment: I face the same issue on ng-focus :-/

Comment: try bind it to `ng-keyup` first?

Answer (score 2):

When `blur` event is fired, u have already lost your focus and the range created.

To get the caret offset just before the div lost focus, I would recommend you save the caret offset every time it changes. That is to say, update it every time `keyup` or `mouseup` is fired or when any other timing u would like to update it.

Check [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oxSBI1?p=preview)

BTW, in this plunkr i used your `getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin` function to calculate the offset. But this function may be not working as expected. It will add some blanks to the content and the caret offset is larger than real.